# Выборка БД в C++

Tags: sql, xsd, visual-c++

Доброго времени суток :)

Создал в MS Visual Studio 2005 проект CLR - Windows Forms. Подключил базу из Access. В ней есть таблица `airo` с колонками: **place** (string), **num** (int), **fio** (string), **pasport** (string), **dates** (datetime). Базу подключил через dataGridView (вытащились компоненты dataSet, BindingSource и TableAdapter). Запросы делаю через DataSet конструктор (редактируя файл AirDataSet.xsd).

Запросы с условием на string и int получаются, а с датой не могу правильно создать, все время говорит что не правильный параметр.

Вот пример запроса, который у меня проходит (place и num - входные параметры, а дату получилось только константно задать, это все дело в файле .xsd):

```
SELECT id, place, num, fio, pasport, dates
FROM   Airo
WHERE  place LIKE '%'+@place+'%' AND num = @num AND dates = #10.10.2013#
```

Как можно задать запрос с датой?

Пробовал:

```
... dates = @dates // ошибки не дает, но и ничего не фильтрует, dates как DateTime
... dates = '#'+@dates+'#' // dates как string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

dates = Format(@dates, "mm-dd-yyyy")

Сначала на примере:

dates = Format('10.10.2013', "mm-dd-yyyy")

Comment: да, все отлично заработало! ) спасибо :)